# Line count of decoded binary content from json response

Tags: python, json, github

I have some code below that counts the number of lines in decoded GitHub binary content and then looks for percent change based on the changes count of a file.  This is contained in a loop within a loop in an if/else statement.  What I have now works, but it outputs the results of each individual file in the pull request.  I would like to write the if/else just once if any of the results in the set of returned files meet the condition in the if statement (else print no file has changed) and then move on to the next set for evaluation.

```
     found = False
     for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():
         if data.filename.endswith((".png",".jpeg",".gif")):
             pass
         else:
             for files_content in [repo.blob(data.sha)]:
                 binary_coded_content = io.BytesIO((base64.b64decode(files_content.content)))
                 tempfile = 'temp'
                 with open(tempfile,'wb') as f:
                     f.write(binary_coded_content.read())
                 num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(tempfile, encoding='utf8') if line.rstrip())
                 if data.changes_count/num_lines > 0.25:
                     found = True
                     break
     if found:
         print("A file has changed by more than 25%", '\n')
     else:
         print("No file has changed by more than 25%", '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to create a *found* variable and test it outside the loop like this

```
found = False # <----
for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():
    if data.filename.endswith((".png",".jpeg",".gif")):
        pass
    else:

        for files_content in [repo.blob(data.sha)]:
             binary_coded_content = io.BytesIO((base64.b64decode(files_content.content)))
             tempfile = 'temp'
             with open(tempfile,'wb') as f:
                 f.write(binary_coded_content.read())
             num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(tempfile, encoding='utf8') if line.rstrip()) 
             if data.changes_count/num_lines > 0.25:
                found = True # <----
                break #<--- break inner loop
        if found:
            break #<--- break outer loop
    if found: # after the loop ended, we check if we found something...
        print("A file has changed by more than 25%")
    else:
        print("No file has changed by more than 25%")
```

Comment: Please disregard my last comment.  It works, but it outputs the same result I had before.  It output the results individually and doesn't evaluate the set and give me output just once

Comment: I declared `found` before the first `for` statement moved the `if found` statement to the same level as the first for statement.  Everything now works as expected.  I will mark this as the answer and update my code in the original post with the fix.

Comment: @DBS - I've fixed the answer to break the outer loop as well